# JIRA integration with Microsoft Test Manager for bug tracking

Tags: mtm, jira

I'm interested in integrating JIRA with Microsoft Test Manager. One of the reasons for this integration is to track bugs in JIRA which was originally logged in Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) i.e log a defect in MTM then have this defect created in JIRA and once the defect has been resolved and is ready for the retest, an update on the bug status made in JIRA would then update the bug status in MTM as ready for the retest.

Answer (score 2):

You have two main options.

A quick web search about JIRA TFS integration returns several connectors, most requiring payment. If your version of TFS is supported by the connectors, that would be your best option, because you would automatically get the MTM integration.

If your version of TFS is not supported, or your organization is not willing to purchase the connector, you're going to need to work with the TFS API (which is not pleasant, but can be done) and the JIRA API to build your own bridge between the two systems.

The only other option I'm aware of is to work with manual exports and imports via spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

- [TFS4JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.spartez.jira.plugins.bork.tfs4jira/cloud/overview) (commercial / free for personal & non profit use)
- [UseTFS](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.pigsty.jira.plugin.usetfs/server/overview) (commercial / free for community and open-source projects)
- [Atlassian](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/archive/PLVS) Connector for Visual Studio (free)

The Atlassian Connector doesn't include full integration, but at least you get to see all JIRA issues within Visual Studio and you can comment on stuff and search for stuff. So basically you are only missing code checkins. It is enough for most purposes - otherwise you have the other two